Problem with pdf file path when executig jar on javafx project
I have a JavaFX application developed in NetBeans that sends emails with pdfs. The application works fine within NetBeans, but when I generate the JAR file and run it, and i  attempt to send an email with an attached PDF file I receive a FileNotFoundException.
This is the code of the method:
public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(String recipientEmail, String subject, String body, String filePath) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER_EMAIL));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Crea el cuerpo del mensaje
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(body);

        // Crea la parte del archivo adjunto
        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    
        attachmentPart.attachFile(new File(filePath));
        System.out.println("ATACHMENTNAME================="+attachmentPart.getFileName());


        // Une el cuerpo del mensaje y la parte del archivo adjunto
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

        // Establece el contenido del mensaje como la combinacion de las partes
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // envia el mensaje
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Email con adjunto enviado correctamente a " + recipientEmail);
    } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error al enviar el email con adjunto", e);
    }
}

And this is when I try to send the email on my controller:
String filePath = "pdfs/" + obtenerRutinaFileName();
System.out.println(filePath);
// Enviar email con rutina adjunta
EmailSender.sendEmailWithAttachment(RegistroEmail.getText(), subject, body, filePath);`


I am not sure you can be helped here.  What is obtenerRutinaFileName()? What is the output of System.out.println(filePath);? What is the output of attachmentPart.getFileName()?  When you do new File(filePath), does the file actually exist at the location specified?  You can test for existence and readability.  You can add information to your question rather than comments to improve the question quality.
